# Why isn't my Unity OnCollisionEnter working in the build, but working in the editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, game-physics

I have a piece of vaulting code for my FPS game and it works fine in the editor but doesnt work at all in the build

ive tried debugging several times but it never works!
I've decompiled the code of my build and the vaulting code is there!
ive looked through my script and script dependencies for errors...
idk whats going on pls help.

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {

        //for vaulting
        if (isVaultNormal(other.GetContact(0).normal) && !crouching && other.gameObject.tag != "NoVault" && !grounded && other.gameObject.isStatic) {

            if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null) return;

            CapsuleCollider col = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();

            Vector3 pos = transform.position;
            pos += transform.forward * forwardPush * col.radius;
            pos -= Vector3.up * col.height / 2f;
            pos += Vector3.up * maxVaultHeight;

            RaycastHit hit;

            Vector3 XZvel = new Vector3(lastMoveSpeed.x, 0f, lastMoveSpeed.z);
            Vector3 dir = new Vector3(lastMoveSpeed.x, 1.8f/2f * XZvel.magnitude, lastMoveSpeed.z).normalized;

            if (Physics.Raycast(pos, Vector3.down, out hit, maxVaultHeight) && !Physics.Raycast(pos + Vector3.up * maxVaultHeight, dir.normalized, forwardPush * col.radius + 0.05f)) {

                if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - (hit.point + Vector3.up * (col.height / 2f)).y) < 0.1f) return;

                if (!Physics.Linecast(hit.point + Vector3.up * 0.1f, hit.point + col.height * Vector3.up, groundMask)) {

                    isVault = true;

                    Vector3 previousPosition = transform.position;

                    transform.position = hit.point + Vector3.up * (col.height / 2f);

                    rb.velocity = new Vector3(lastMoveSpeed.x, 0f, lastMoveSpeed.z) * 0.4f;

                    Vector3 offset = transform.position - previousPosition;

                    CameraController.SetVault(-offset);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i tried removing all references to debug.log and stuff.